# Offers home delivery vs home delivers

Tags: verbs, adverbs

In which of these 2 sentences is the verb "Home deliver" used correctly, in compliance with the rest of the sentence?

ABC **offers home delivery** of pharmaceuticals, compounded medications, and wellness diets to pet owners.

VS

ABC **home delivers** pharmaceuticals, compounded medications, and wellness diets to pet owners.

Comment: The first one is correct.

Comment: Can you please provide a small explanation for your answer? Is the second version entirely wrong? Thank you :)

Comment: Home delivers is not common in English.  Home can be an adverb, but, home delivery is a noun that *is* common in English.  Home is usually used as an adverb in the form:  He went home, etc.

Comment: I disagree with @David; they both sound legit to me. The second even sounds more natural, whereas the first sounds like brochure speak.

Comment: 'Offers home delivery' might be used when ABC does not deliver it themselves, but contracts it out.

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt, ask Google:

[image: Home Delivers pic]

In the comments, Bradd Szonye says that "the first sounds like brochure speak". I'd disagree with this as "**home delivers**" is definitely brochure speak as it's not a commonly used phrase, where as "**home delivery**" is much more common.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, "home delivery" is far more common, and "home" as an adverb is generally used other than in "home delivers". That said, "home delivers" is immediately understandable, and probably most people would read it in context without batting an eyelid.

I suspect that if you asked people what "home delivery" usually refers to, they would name newspapers, furniture, groceries, pizza, and the like. A serious pharmaceuticals company may want to disassociate from more trivial kinds of home shopping/home delivery and thus choose a less cliched, less "fun" sounding term. This is entirely a stylistic choice. It should be weighed against what is standard, but, if there is no effect at the expense of comprehension, it is not an invalid choice.